# Making Rails #destroy_all run faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I want to run `Alarm.destroy_all`, though, each alarm is associated to many `AlarmEvent`s, and each `AlarmEvent` is associated to many `AlarmEvent::Measurement`s,being both associations marked as `:dependent=>destroy`

So, when I invoke Alarm.destroy all, this invokation is taking ages to run. Is there any way I could make it faster? How?

Until now I've tried `Alarm.joins(:alarm_events).destroy_all` and it is still slow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The faster alternative to `destroy_all` is `delete_all` but this won't chase down and destroy any dependencies, nor will it trigger any `before_destroy` or `after_destroy` hooks.

If you're really concerned about speed, you'd probably re-write this with this in mind. You can even rack it up as a series of conditions:

```
Alarm.delete_all(:id => alarm_ids)
AlarmEvent.delete_all(:alarm_id => alarm_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved it by replacing the invokation with:

```
Alarm.transaction{
  AlarmEvent::Measurement.destroy_all
  AlarmEvent.destroy_all
  Alarm.destroy_all
}
```

This still garantees that the destroy-associated proceedures are ran, but it pre-executes a big part of them, thus avoiding a lot of "nested queries".

Comment: This solution is only sensible in the case that you want to destroy every existing `AlarmEvent` whenever you call `Alarm.destroy_all`. Probably what you want, but just a warning.

Comment: Yeap. This solution is ok for my model. Though, It's not good if the measurements and the alarm events are meant to exist without being connected to any alarm_event or alarm, respectively.